# Converting suspendCancellableCoroutine into callbackFlow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I have the following function.

```
 suspend fun result() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Int> {continuation ->
      val callback = object : Callback {
            continuation.resume(value)
      }
 }
```

and then I call result in a Coroutine as follows:

```
 someCoroutine {
     when (result()){
          x -> doSomething
          y -> doSomething
           ...
     }
 }
```

It works, but I keep getting the error when its called again:

Uncaught exception: Already resumed, but proposed with update.

I figured I need a callbackFlow instead, but I'm not too sure as to how to implement it. Here's what I have so far.

```
 suspend fun result() = callbackFlow<Int> {
      val callback = object : Callback {
            trySendBlocking(value)
      }
      awaitClose()
 }
```

I'm guessing I have to use collect(), but I don't know how to process it in the coroutine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do on subsequent callback calls? Do you want to run `doSomething` each time or run it only once and ignore further callbacks?

Comment: The latter, but Sergio's answer worked for me.

Comment: Hmm, Sergio's answer actually does the first. But maybe you adapted it to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use values emitted by `Flow` you need to use one of the [terminal operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#terminal-flow-operators), for example `collect`:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
   result().collect { value ->
       when (value) {
          x -> doSomething
          y -> doSomething
          ...
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, result does not need to be a suspend function if it directly returns a Flow.